# Julia: local in module scope

Tags: julia

When generating a not explicitly generated version of a function, [`@ngenerate`](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.3/devdocs/cartesian/#supplying-the-number-of-expressions) runs

```
eval(quote
     local _F_
     $localfunc # Definition of _F_ for the requested value of N
     _F_
end)
```

Since [`eval`](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.3/stdlib/base/?highlight=eval#Base.eval) runs in the scope of the current module, not the function, I wonder what is the effect of `local` in this context. As far as I know, the languange documentation only mentions the use of [`local`](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.3/manual/variables-and-scoping/#scope-of-variables) inside function definitions.

---

To give some background why this question arose: I frequently need to code loops of the form

```
function foo(n::Int)
    s::Int = 0
    for i in 1:1000000000
        for j in 1:n
            s += 1
        end
    end
    return s
end
```

where `n <= 10` (of course, in my actual code the loops are such that they cannot just be reduced to O(1)). Because this code is very simple for the compiler but demanding at runtime, it turns out to be beneficial to simply recompile the loops with the required value of `n` each time `foo` is called.

```
function clever_foo(n::Int)
    eval(quote
        function clever_foo_impl()
            s::Int = 0
            for i in 1:1000000000
                s += $(Expr(:call,:+,[1 for j in 1:n]...))
            end
            return s
        end
    end)
    return clever_foo_impl()
end
```

However, I am not sure whether I am doing this the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's to prevent `_F_` from being visible in the global method cache.

If you'll call `clever_foo` with the same `n` repeatedly, you can do even better by saving the compiled function in a `Dict`. That way you don't have to recompile it each time.

Comment: Is preventing `_F_` from being visible in the global method cache just a performance optimisation, or does it actually change something?

Comment: With my current approach, I've run into things similar to https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/9869, and I neither understand the details of how this comes about nor how it can be avoided. Mostly because of simplicity, I switched to defining `clever_foo_impl` as an anonymous function invoked through `eval(()->begin #code end)()`, and with that the anomaly seems to have been eliminated. Is this approach save?